# Two UIScrollView only one appearing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So Im making a two `UIscrollview` in my view. I'm using `Ray Wenderlich`'s `Custom Image Picker`. But when I load it, only shows 1 imagepicker. I want to be able to load two image picker. I think Im doing something wrong with `initWithCoder` part. Cant seem to initialize it properly. Is it possible to have two ivars `self`. Sorry kinda new to iphoneDev. Thanks for your help.

Here's my whole implementation:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        _images =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _thumbs =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        //THIS IS WHERE I THINK ITS WRONG but the upper part seems to be okay.
        _images2 =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _thumbs2 =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image {
    [_images addObject:image];
    [_thumbs addObject:[image imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)]];
}
- (void)addImage2:(UIImage *)image {
    [_images2 addObject:image];
    [_thumbs2 addObject:[image imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)]];
}


- (void) createScrollView {
    self.slotBg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(43, 370, 300, 143)];
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.slotBg.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
    [self.slotBg.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:self.slotBg];
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,300.0f,134.0f)];
    [slotBg addSubview:scrollView];

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < _thumbs.count; ++i) {

        UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*60+10, row*60+10, 60, 60);
        [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = i; 

        [scrollView addSubview:button];

        if (column == 4) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        } else {
            column++;
        }

    }

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(330, (row+1) * 60 + 10)];
}

- (void) createScrollView2 {
    self.slotBg2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(362, 370, 300, 143)];
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.slotBg.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
    [self.slotBg.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:self.slotBg];

    UIScrollView *scrollView2 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,300.0f,134.0f)];
    [slotBg addSubview:scrollView2];

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < _thumbs2.count; ++i) {

        UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs2 objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*60+10, row*60+10, 60, 60);
        [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonClicked2:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = i; 

        [scrollView2 addSubview:button];

        if (column == 4) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        } else {
            column++;
        }

    }

    [scrollView2 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(330, (row+1) * 60 + 10)];

}



- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger slotBG = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];

    if(slotBG == 1){
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [button removeFromSuperview];
    [_images objectAtIndex:button.tag];
    [_images removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%lu.png", button.tag]];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"image removed");
    } else if (slotBG == 2){
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        [button removeFromSuperview];
        [_images objectAtIndex:button.tag];
        [_images removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstSlotImages%lu.png", button.tag]];
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
        NSLog(@"image removed");

    } else if (slotBG == 3){
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        [button removeFromSuperview];
        [_images objectAtIndex:button.tag];
        [_images removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%lu.png", button.tag]];
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
        NSLog(@"image removed");
    }   
}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked2:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button2 = (UIButton *)sender;
    [button2 removeFromSuperview];
    [_images2 objectAtIndex:button2.tag];
    [_images2 removeObjectAtIndex:button2.tag];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"secondSlotImages%lu.png", button2.tag]];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"image removed");
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSInteger slotBG = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];

    if(slotBG == 1){
        [mode1 setHighlighted:YES];

        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
        { 
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%d.png", i]]; 
            NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);
            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
                [self addImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 

                NSLog(@"file exists");
            } 
        } 
            NSLog(@"Count : %d", [_images count]);
        [self createScrollView];

    } else if(slotBG == 2 ){
        [mode2 setHighlighted:YES];
        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
        { 

            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstSlotImages%d.png", i]]; 
            NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);
            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
                [self addImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 

                NSLog(@"file exists");
            } 
        }
            NSLog(@"Count : %d", [_images count]);  

            [self createScrollView];

        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
        { 
                    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"secondSlotImages%d.png", i]]; 
            NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);
            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
                [self addImage2:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 
                 NSLog(@"file exists");
            } 
        }
        NSLog(@"Count : %d", [_images2 count]);  

        [self createScrollView2];


    }  else if( slotBG == 3){
        [mode3 setHighlighted:YES];

        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
        { 
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%d.png", i]]; 
            NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);
            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
                [self addImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 

                NSLog(@"file exists");
            } 
        } 
        NSLog(@"Count : %d", [_images count]);
        [self createScrollView];

    }     




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `createScrollView2` method, you alloc self.slotBg2, but then only reference self.slotBg when adding to your view. Then you add your scrollview2 to the original slotBg.

Comment: In your createScrollView2 method, you need to only be referencing slotBg2 and scrollview2, however, you are still using slotBg so the second scroll view is inserted over the top of the first scrollview.

Comment: Thanks. Done it. Didn't see it,carelessness of mine. :)